# jquery mouseleave() being ignored

Tags: jquery, menu, mouseleave

Hi I am using mouseleave() on a dropdown navigation menu so that when the user leaves the submenu dropdown the submenu disappears, however it seems to be ignoring it and the menu remains. Any ideas? Here is the site and code:

http://www.maiagifts.co.uk/about-us/info_1.html

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#newcats li').addClass('parentitem');
    $('.newsubs li').removeClass('parentitem');
    $('.newsubs').hide();                      

    $('.parentitem').hover(              
    function(){
    $(this).children('.newsubs').show();
    $(this).siblings('.parentitem').children('.newsubs').hide();

 });


    //problem is here//
    $('.newsubs').mouseleave(
    function(){
    $(this).hide();
    });
    //problem is here//


    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Try with `.on`

```
$('.newsubs').on('mouseleave', function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

If you are using jquery version less than 1.7.1 then use `.live()`

Comment: won't work for OP. Try $("body").on in the dev console of the site linked to in the question

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
   $('.newsubs').mouseleave(
    function(){
    $('.newsubs').hide();
    });
```

Would that achieve what you want?

Answer (score 0):

if you look in the development console of the site your are linking to you will see a bunch of error messages one of them (repeated) being `"Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'mouseleave'"` so the above code attaching the handler is never executed.

`.on` isn't defined either and I'm guessing that they are all a result of the first error message you have which is 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'guid' of undefined` on line 91 in jquery.

In other words the jQuery script isn't executed in it's full length and `mouseleave`and other methods such as `on` is never defined.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the hover() method to .mouseover() and started working. I wonder if because i used hover() with a function only for the mouseover part of it, jquery had already decided it had an empty mouseleave so ignored the second one. just a guess.